# React Native init does not create Xcode project

Tags: xcode, reactjs, react-native

When I run `react-native init application-name`, no XCode project gets generated.

The `node_modules` dir and `package.json` file is generated and `npm install` is run, but immediately after the 'npm dependency graph' is printed, it stops.

The last line of output is `rbenv: no such command`exec'`, which seems rather strange as this has nothing to do with rbenv/Ruby.

Full log output:

```
 react-native init ReactiveNews
This will walk you through creating a new React Native project in /Users/taylor/Git/ReactiveNews
npm WARN engine makeerror@1.0.10: wanted: {"node":"0.6.x"} (current: {"node":"0.10.38","npm":"1.4.28"})

> ws@0.4.31 install /Users/taylor/Git/ReactiveNews/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/bufferutil.node
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/bufferutil.node: Finished
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/validation/src/validation.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/validation.node
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/validation.node: Finished
npm WARN engine tmpl@1.0.3: wanted: {"node":"0.6.x"} (current: {"node":"0.10.38","npm":"1.4.28"})
react-native@0.2.1 node_modules/react-native
├── absolute-path@0.0.0
├── stacktrace-parser@0.1.1
├── react-timer-mixin@0.13.1
├── underscore@1.7.0
├── q@1.0.1
├── yargs@1.3.2
├── debug@2.1.3 (ms@0.7.0)
├── source-map@0.1.31 (amdefine@0.1.0)
├── optimist@0.6.1 (wordwrap@0.0.2, minimist@0.0.10)
├── worker-farm@1.1.0 (xtend@4.0.0, errno@0.1.2)
├── rebound@0.0.12
├── sane@1.0.1 (watch@0.10.0, fb-watchman@0.0.0, minimatch@0.2.14, walker@1.0.6)
├── uglify-js@2.4.17 (uglify-to-browserify@1.0.2, async@0.2.10, yargs@1.3.3, source-map@0.1.34)
├── jstransform@10.0.1 (base62@0.1.1, esprima-fb@13001.1.0-dev-harmony-fb)
├── joi@5.1.0 (topo@1.0.2, isemail@1.1.1, hoek@2.12.0, moment@2.9.0)
├── connect@2.8.3 (uid2@0.0.2, methods@0.0.1, fresh@0.1.0, pause@0.0.1, cookie-signature@1.0.1, buffer-crc32@0.2.1, qs@0.6.5, bytes@0.2.0, cookie@0.1.0, formidable@1.0.14, send@0.1.2)
├── module-deps@3.5.6 (inherits@2.0.1, shallow-copy@0.0.1, minimist@0.2.0, subarg@0.0.1, stream-combiner2@1.0.2, parents@1.0.1, readable-stream@1.0.33, resolve@0.7.4, through2@0.4.2, duplexer2@0.0.2, concat-stream@1.4.7, browser-resolve@1.8.1, JSONStream@0.7.4, detective@3.1.0)
├── react-tools@0.13.0-rc2 (commoner@0.10.1)
└── ws@0.4.31 (tinycolor@0.0.1, options@0.0.6, commander@0.6.1, nan@0.3.2)
rbenv: no such command `exec'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with the init.sh script under node_modules/react-native, rbenv threw the `` rbenv: no such command `exec' `` every time it was executed. I first solved it by running it directly through rbenv with `rbenv exec` but was able to solve the issue entirely by turning the rbenv bundler plugin off and on again.

Comment: I think you can accept your own answer - if you've fully resolved the problem it might make sense to do so to help out others who stumble on this.

Comment: Just had to wait two days to do it.

Comment: What do you do now? I don't see any init.sh script in that folder.

Comment: No idea, haven't looked at React Native since this so I don't know how it's handled these days.